# subtract count of metric in to specific time range in grafana

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to subtract count of a metric from now and for example 5 min ago.
how can I do that?

This is not work:

```
count(istio_requests_total{destination_workload=~"production-api") -  count(istio_requests_total{destination_workload=~"production-api") [5m:5m]
```

Each returned metric values is like:

```
istio_requests_total{connection_security_policy="none", destination_app="unknown", destination_canonical_revision="latest", destination_canonical_service="production-api", destination_cluster="Kubernetes", destination_port="81", destination_principal="unknown", destination_service="production-api.production.svc.cluster.local", destination_service_name="production-api", destination_service_namespace="production", destination_version="unknown", destination_workload="production-api", destination_workload_namespace="production", instance="10.233.64.228:15090", job="envoy-stats", path="/favicon.ico", reporter="destination", request_duration="0.013466636s", request_host="api.test.com", request_protocol="http", request_size="0", request_time="2022-11-15T21:41:36.699467Z", request_total_size="1233", response_code="404", response_flags="-", source_app="unknown", source_canonical_revision="latest", source_canonical_service="unknown", source_cluster="unknown", source_principal="unknown", source_version="unknown", source_workload="unknown", source_workload_namespace="unknown", url_path="/favicon.ico"}  1 @1668673800
```

because of labels like request_duration and request_time each, returned metric is different than each other.

when running query I got this error:

> Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:197: parse error: binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types

I also tested something like this?

```
delta(count(istio_requests_total{destination_workload=~"production-api"))[5m])
```

Comment: Use offset to get "previous" value

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
count(istio_requests_total{destination_workload=~"production-api") -  count(istio_requests_total{destination_workload=~"production-api") offset 5m
```

See more info in Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier).

Comment: When the range is very large, the offset solution starts giving no data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need calculating the total number of [istio](https://istio.io/) requests over the last 5 minutes, then the following PromQL query should work:

```
sum(increase(istio_requests_total[5m]))
```

It works in the following way:

1. It calculates the number of requests over the last 5 minutes individually per each [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series) with the `istio_requests_total` name with the `increase(istio_requests_total[5m])`. See [increase() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase)
2. It sums per-series values returned from the previous step with `sum(...)` aggregate function - see [sum() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum).